# Can't boot into ubuntu 19.04 atfer move some file from download to root/usr with mv command

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.04, bootloader

I was trying to move some files from my Downloads directory to the `/usr` with the `mv` command. But the screen became black. After restarting, I see the following text on the black screen:

```
[    0.815695] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000e
/dev/sda9: clean, 284048/4136960 files 3693627/16528128 blocks
```

Here is an image of the error screen:

[image: error screen]

Comment: Save you data and install new. Without knowing what you did exactly, it is difficult to help

Comment: Thanks. But how can i save my data??

Comment: I was tring to to move a folder home/sagor/download/usr to root/usr

Comment: with a live-session and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync